# Update and select a field based on a foreignt table that contains several rows based on the most recent register

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I have the next problem with a query and next with an update:
I have main users table as follows (I only show important fields):

```
+----------------------+
|id|name |collective_id|
+----------------------+
|1 |dark |NULL         |
+----------------------+
|2 |thor |NULL         |
+----------------------+
|3 |vinky|NULL         |
+----------------------+
```

And the foreign table related with users by users.id (FK is contrats.user_id) named contracts:

```
-------------------------------------------------
|id|user_id|ts_from|ts_expire|type|collective_id|
-------------------------------------------------
|1 |1      |1000000|2000000  |1   |NULL         |
|2 |1      |1000001|2000001  |1   |NULL         |
|3 |1      |1000001|2000001  |3   |15           |
|4 |1      |1000002|2000002  |3   |8            |
|5 |2      |1000000|2200000  |2   |NULL         |
```

The query result I want is the next:

```
-----------------------
|user_id|collective_id|
-----------------------
|1      |8            |
|2      |NULL         |
|3      |NULL         |
```

The result is the union of both tables, related with the field `contracts.user_id=users.id` with `LEFT JOIN`, but taking care that `collective_id` is the most recent field in `contracts` table by `ts_expire` field and having that `type = 3`, that's the reason why the selected `collective_id` for `user_id` `1` is `8`, not `15` and the other users doesn't contains any `collective_id` due they don't have any contract with `type = 3`. Do you understand?

The last question related with this issue is that my users table contains a `collective_id` field too that should be updated with this value, how should be the `UPDATE` query based on this criteria to update users.collective_id field?

Many thanks

Daniel from Barcelona (Expert in php programming and not a lot of mysql complex queries)

I've tested several queries, but didn't work:

```
UPDATE `users` 
SET `collective_id` = (
    SELECT `collective_id` 
    FROM `contrats` 
    WHERE 
        `vigency` = 1 
        AND `type` = 3 
        AND `user_id` = 1 
    ORDER BY `ts_expire` DESC 
    LIMIT 1
) 
WHERE `users`.`id`=1;
```

This worked but only for one user specified, not the whole users table.

```
UPDATE `users` u, contracts 
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT `user_id`, `collective_id` 
    FROM `contratos` 
    WHERE 
        `users_id`= u.`id` 
        AND `vigency`= 1 
        AND `type` = 3
) contracts ON contracts.`user_id`=u.`id` 
SET `collective_id` = contracts.`collective_id` 
WHERE 1;
```

This worked wrong, by updating whole users.collective_id with the same value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the select query, you can `left join` and filter with a correlated subquery:

```
select 
    u.user_id,
    c.collective_id
from users u
left join contrats c
    on  c.user_id = u.user_id
    and c.vigency = 1
    and c.type = 3
    and c.ts_expire = (
        select max(ts_expire)
        from contracts c1
        where 
            c1.user_id = c.user_id 
            and c1.vigency = c.vigency 
            and c1.type = c.type
    )
```

Your update query is almost there, you just need to *correlate* the subquery with the outer query

```
update users u set collective_id = (
    select collective_id 
    from contrats c
    where 
        c.vigency = 1 
        and c.type = 3 
        and c.user_id = u.user_id
        order by c.ts_expire 
        desc limit 1
    )
```

Please note that this will set to `null` records for which the subquery comes up empty.

Comment: It worked! Thanks! The update has very sense, but the SELECT is very strange to deduce, but it worked